# When I searching any Listview item and then going to click desire item, it always open first position of List View

Tags: java, android, listview, searchview

MainActivity.class
The problem is when I am going to search any desired item from listview and click on that then it always open first position item which I am added in the program not desired item when I had searched.

```
package com.example.rushikesh.first;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import com.example.rushikesh.first.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class Basic_programs extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener 
{

private SearchView mSearchView;
private ListView mListView;
private AdView mAdView;
private final String[] mStrings = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_prog_list);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mStrings));
    mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    setupSearchView();

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            String  itemValue    = (String) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if(position == 0) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.FIRST_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.SECOND_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 2) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.THIRD_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 3) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.FOURTH_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 4) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.FIFTH_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 5) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.SIXTH_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 6) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEVENTH_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 7) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.EIGHT_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 8) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.NINTH_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 9) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.TENTH_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 10) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.ELEVEN_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 11) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.TWELVE_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 12) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.THIRTEEN_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 13) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.FOURTEEN_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 14) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.FIFTEEN_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 15) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.SIXTEEN_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 16) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEVENTEEN_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 17) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.EIGHTEEN_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 18) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.NINETEEN_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 19) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.TWENTY_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 20) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.TWENTYONE_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 21) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.TWENTYTWO_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 22) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.TWENTYTHREE_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 23) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.TWENTYFOUR_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 24) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.TWENTYFIVE_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 25) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.TWENTYSIX_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 26) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.TWENTYSEVEN_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 27) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.TWENTYEIGHT_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 28) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.TWENTYNINE_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 29) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.THIRTY_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 30) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.THIRTYONE_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 31) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.THIRTY_TWO");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 32) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.THIRTY_THREE");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(position == 33) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.THIRTY_FOUR");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });

}


private void setupSearchView() {
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("e.g. Factorial number");
}

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        mListView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        mListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Cheeses.class activity

```
package com.example.rushikesh.first;

public class Cheeses {

public static final String[] sCheeseStrings = {
        "Hello World!", "Addition of two numbers", "Add two numbers in range of integers(4 bytes)", "Factorial number taking user input", "calculating factorial of large numbers",
        "Odd or Even number", "Odd or Even number (Second method)", "Reverse number", "Get input from user in Java",
        "If else program in Java", "Nested If Else program",
        "Print multiplication table", "For loop program in Java", "For loop program to print Stars Pattern",
        "For loop program to print an Alphabets",
        "While loop program to print an Alphabet", "Do-while program to print an Alphabet", "Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius",
        "Swap two numbers using third variable", "Swap two numbers without using third variable",
        "Reverse a string", "Reverse a string using String Buffer class", "Java program to get Ip address",
        "Print prime numbers", "Check palindrome number",
        "Factorial number", "Factorial number using Recursion", "Fibonacci Series in Java without using recursion",
        "Fibonacci Series in Java using recursion", "Search a word inside a string", "Convert integer into hex",
        "Java For loop Thread Sleep method Example", "Thread example by Extending Thread Class",
        "Thread example by Implementing Runnable Interface"

};



}
```

Comment: Why do you save the clicked list item position, which is int, in an String variable?!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your case when you enter text in search view it filter out the matching items from array adapter.

So all items of array redefines their positions which are not same when you set the array adapter.

Here, you have to find the position of a selected result from **sCheeseStrings**

for that you can find below lines of code. please ask if you have any doubt.

```
      String itemValue = (String) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

      int itemPosition = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < mStrings.length; i++) {
                if (itemValue.equalsIgnoreCase(mStrings[i])) {
                    itemPosition = i;
                }
            }

            if (itemPosition == 0) {
                String content = "android.intent.action.FIRST_PROG";
                Intent i = new Intent(content);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if (itemPosition == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.SECOND_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            if (itemPosition == 2) {
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.THIRD_PROG");
                startActivity(i);
            }
```